# Selenium Test - Gather information from a page and insert/update in table

Tags: java, mysql, selenium

I am kinda building a bot/script(but actually it will be a selenium test) for learning purpose.
I want it to gather some info from the page, insert/update into a table / compare with the existing one and if it's different then update/insert.

I've identified the elements that I wish to use on the page, I've done the connection with the db and managed to make a select *, but I can't 
manage to make an insert or update.

So the main idea is:
I wish to gather the resources levels and store them
Mines levels and store them

After this is done I'm going to make some conditions, but first I wish to finish with the db and this is the part I can't manage so far no matter what I try.

```
public class dbCon {
public static void main(String[] args)
  { 
    try
    {       
      String myDriver = "org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver";
      String myUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ogame";
      Class.forName(myDriver);
      Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(myUrl, user,pass);
      Statement stmt = null;
      String query = "SELECT * FROM resources";
      String query2 = "SELECT * FROM mines_levels";

      Statement st = conn.createStatement();
      Statement st2 = conn.createStatement();

      ResultSet res1 = st.executeQuery(query);
      ResultSet res2 = st2.executeQuery(query2);

       while (res1.next()&&res2.next())
      {
        String id = res1.getString("id_ressources");
        String metal= res1.getString("Metal");
        String crystal= res1.getString("Crystal");
        String id2 = res2.getString("id_mines");
        String metal2= res2.getString("Metal_mine");
        String crystal2= res2.getString("Crystal_mine");
        System.out.format("%s, %s, %s\n",id2,metal2,
        System.out.format("%s, %s, %s\n",id,metal,crystal);
        System.out.format("%s, %s, %s\n",id,metal,crystal);
      }

      st.close();
      stmt.close();
    }

    catch (Exception e)
    {
      System.err.println("Got an exception! ");
      System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
  }
}
```

I have 2 classes that I wish to use:

```
public class MinesLevelsRequirements extends PageObject{
@FindBy(css=".supply1")
private WebElementFacade MetalMine;

@FindBy(css=".supply2")
private WebElementFacade CrystalMine;

@FindBy(css=".supply3")
private WebElementFacade DeuteriumMine;

@FindBy(css=".supply4")
private WebElementFacade EnergyMine;

@FindBy(css=".tooltip js_hideTipOnMobile help overlay")
private WebElementFacade MinesReqTo;

@FindBy(css="detailTableRow currentlevel")
private WebElementFacade MinesReq;

public void MetalMine() {
    MetalMine.click();          
            }

public void CrystalMine() {
    CrystalMine.click();            
            }

public void DeuteriumMine() {
    DeuteriumMine.click();          
            }

public void EnergyMine() {
    CrystalMine.click();            
            }

public void MinesReqTo(){
    MinesReqTo.click();
}

public void MinesReq(){

}
```

The second one:

```
public class MinesLevels extends PageObject {

@FindBy(css="#buttonz>#building>.button1>.supply1>.buildingimg>.detail_button tooltip js_hideTipOnMobile slideIn>span>span>text()")
private WebElementFacade MetalMineLevel;

@FindBy(css="#buttonz>#building>.button2>.supply2>.buildingimg>.detail_button tooltip js_hideTipOnMobile slideIn>span>span>text()")
private WebElementFacade CrystalMineLevel;

@FindBy(css="#buttonz>#building>.button3>.supply3>.buildingimg>.detail_button tooltip js_hideTipOnMobile slideIn>span>span>text()")
private WebElementFacade DeuteriumMineLevel;

@FindBy(css="#buttonz>#building>.button4>.supply4>.buildingimg>.detail_button tooltip js_hideTipOnMobile slideIn>span>span>text()")
private WebElementFacade EnergyMineLevel;

public Integer MetalMineLevel() {
    return Integer.parseInt(MetalMineLevel.getText());
}

public Integer CrystalMineLevel() {
    return Integer.parseInt(CrystalMineLevel.getText());
}

public Integer DeuteriumMineLevel() {
    return Integer.parseInt(DeuteriumMineLevel.getText());
}

public Integer EnergyMineLevel() {
    return Integer.parseInt(EnergyMineLevel.getText());
}
```

}

Thanks to anyone who can help me even a bit!

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should ask your question when you have it complete: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Edited it and removed what wasn't finished, since I'll need more time to work on that.

Thanks :)